# How to load constants from service to directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to load language constants from service to a directive and show them to user.
I have discovered that if I just use {{}} in div, then the text is not rendered.
However, by adding any character, i.e. '.' will make it load.

I would be grateful, if someone can explain, what is going on behind scenes and why I need those extra characters.

**Directive code**

```
directive('projectHeader', ['LangService', function(langService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function postLink($scope, tElement, tAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.lang = langService.getLocalisedStrings();
        },

        templateUrl: "app/header.html"
    };
}])
```

**header.html**

```
<div class="header">{{lang.header}}.</div>
```

**LangService definition**

```
angular.module('project.services').factory('LangService', ['$http', function ($http) {
var langConstants;

return {
    init: function(lang) {
        $http.get("app/lang/"+ lang + ".properties").then(function(response){
            langConstants = response.data;
        });
    },

    getLocalisedStrings: function () {
        return langConstants;
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: i don't see [why it shouldn't work without the dot](http://plnkr.co/edit/WX1Bf4FG2A6UFp3tm9iP?p=preview). there must be something else going on. how does `LangService` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a race between the postLink and the $http in the init method. Try adding a watch on getLocalisedStrings() in the directive so that $scope.lang gets updated as soon as getLocalisedStrings() returns some data.